# Monitoring a nohup process in linux / redirecting standard output to a file?

Tags: linux, background-process, nohup, svnsync

```
# nohup svnsync synchronize svn://www.mysite.com/repos &
```

I'm running the above and it seems to be working fine (disk usage is increasing), but I'm not seeing any logging in nohup.out

How can I redirect standard output so that it is visible within this file as well (while keeping the nohup part intact)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just explicitly redirect its output:

```
# nohup svnsync synchronize svn://www.mysite.com/repos > nohup.out &
```

Comment: actually it was working fine (but there were long gaps between updates), but your answer looks like it would work